# Passing Activity or Context to other instance

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

Can you please tell me whats the best practice to pass `activity` or `context` to other instance(;)

But...,

- What is better to pass? `Activity` or `Context`
- Is good idea to have the `Activity` as Global (public static Activity activity)

[here](http://pastebin.com/fv1Z9Uwc) is my code. What would you change? (based on good android practices)

Comment: you dont need the Activity or the context tho, as you can just call view.getContext() in your toast message and you should be fine

Answer (score 9):

Passing an `Activity` into another object that does not specifically require the `Activity` object is usually a bad idea. `Activity` extends `Context` so it works to satisfy a method that requires `Context`.

In your case, you can get the `Context` from the `View` that is passed into the method. However, if you need the `Context` for other purposes, you should avoid passing `Activity` and do something like `Activity.getApplicationContext()`.

The reason for this is if the object you pass an `Activity` into lives longer than the `Activity`, the reference to the `Activity` will prevent Android from doing proper Garbage Collection (`GC`) and consume unnecessary memory. This is called a "memory leak".

EDIT:

To handle situations where you need to call `Activity.findViewById()` keep these things in mind. First, that is a `View` method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) so be sure to call it from the correct view.

Second, if you need a `View` from an `Activity` you should pass it in as a `WeakReference`

Comment: Ty. So, lets say i have an class (example: `class MyListener implements GridView.MultipleChoiceListener {...}` and i wan't to find an control. How i will do `findViewById` ? For example: http://pastebin.com/KDDCqfBP

Answer (score 0):

`Context` is an entity which provides global information about application or activity. You can get the context by invoking `getApplicationContext()`, `getContext()`, `getBaseContext()` or `this` (when in the activity class).
`Context` is tied with lifecycle of its activity/application and commonly used for creating new objects, accessing resources e.t.c.

In your code you can use `Context` as a first parameter in `Toast.makeText` . It's also common to have global `Context` object for a class. You may read some explanation about `Context` usage [here](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/)

You may need Activity object for example if you need to [start new activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) and create `Intent` object.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Interface and implement in your Activity or Service or Intentservice class and return context as a callback

```
public interface ContextWraperSolution {
    Context getContext();
}
```

Pass this interface as a constructor parameter to non-Activity class and use it like

```
insanaceContextWraper.getContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

To use context from another instance, you can create static variable then refer to it in instance you wish to use

```
public class MyClassA(){
     public static Context context;

     private void setcontext()
     {
         context = MyClassA.this;
     }

}

public class MyClassB(){
     private Context classA_context = MyClassA.context;    
}
```