# show I require Context instead of Activity as in-parameter?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working a android sdk. I ask user input activity as a parameter, although I think "Context" is enough for my case, also from sdk's user's view, "Context" will be easer for coding. But I see some other sdk ask user pass the "Activity" as in-parameter, Is there any specific reason for "Activity"?

Comment: it all depends. "Context" will be ok in most cases.

Comment: What are you using it for, and how long do you need to retain the reference?

Comment: You should ask for a Context unless there's some function on Activity that you absolutely need to call (for example a permissions check).

Answer (score 0):

Context is base class of all Application, services and Activities , three main components of Android application. Most of work can be done via Context object. So if your sdk is OK with context, it is better to use Context. For ,more details check this thread. [Passing Activity or Context to other instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162348/passing-activity-or-context-to-other-instance)

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for a Context unless there's some function on Activity that you absolutely need to call (for example a permissions check).  This will allow your library to be used in a Service or BroadcastReceiver as well.