# How to pass native method to thread in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have one `MainActivity`, one `Thread(RunJNIThread)` and one `jniClass.c`. Because `JNI` will block `UI` thread, so I use Thread to run `jniClass.cpp`.
I used `Activity` to call `MainActivity.StartJNI()` in Thread, after I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162348/passing-activity-or-context-to-other-instance) that said "Passing an `Activity` into another `object` is usually a bad idea ".

So how to pass a native method which defined in `MainActivity` to `Thread`? Not using `Activity`.

MainActivity.java

```
public RunJNIThread thread;
thread = new RunJNIThread(this);
....
static {
   System.loadLibrary("jniClass");
}
public native void StartJNI();
...
```

RunJNIThread.java

```
private MainActivity mainActivity;
getFrameThread(MainActivity mainActivity){
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity; //Not Good
}
public void run(){
    while(!Stop){
        mainActivity.StartJNI(); //how to replace this with better way
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new view as interface

```
interface MyView{
    void callMethod();
}
```

then you implement this view in your Main Activity

```
MainActivity implements MyView
```

when your create the thread class you can pass context if it is needed , and view as parameters.

```
thread = new RunJNIThread(this,this)
```

and your Thread class' constructor should be ;

```
public class RunJNIThread{
    public void RunJNIThread(Context context , MyView view){
        this.context = context;
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

when you want to call your main activity function. you can call "callMethod()"

```
public void run(){
while(!Stop){
    view.callMethod();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in your main activity, overrided callMethod

```
@Override
public void callMethod(){
    StartJNI();
}
```